# Does a user in review mode lose out on reputation if the user does not comment

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, downvote-reason

Does a user in review mode downvote a post without commenting do lose out on reputation gained ?

I lost due to downvoting on this particular answer . Take a look

[Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35376669/1172914)

Comment: Comments never generate rep. The effects of votes on posts aren't ever related to whether you comment or not. I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: Currently I had a rep of 501 on stackoverflow with privilege to review . I review some posts and downvoted which I did not found suitable on stack site , but then my rep too came down to 500 for one of the post I downvoted but not commented anything on it

Comment: Downvoting answers costs 1 rep, whether you comment or not, whether from review or anywhere else.

Comment: But if an answer contains ... "Just Google it " I dont think any one will vote it , besides others will think twice after losing out on rep and give more power to reviewer in this case for genuine downvotes on answers

Comment: The rep is refunded if the post is deleted. Which should happen eventually for that sort of answer.

Comment: Ok @Mat , will wait for it

Comment: That being said, if you're worried about losing rep through downvoting answers as part of the review process, either don't downvote, or don't review altogether. A good reviewer puts the site's interests above their own - that's why they *review*.

Comment: Your comment seems offensive and rude , that the basics of Stack site

Comment: @Yatin: BoltClock's comment is neither offensive nor rude. You should keep it in mind. Bad reviews are worse than no reviews.

Comment: Seems like a grouping , 6 downvotes for post and 6 up votes for Mat's and @Bolt 's comments

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia

Answer (score 10):

Downvotes on answers cost you 1 reputation point. This is—among other reasons—to discourage "strategic" downvoting, whereby someone downvotes all of the competing answers on a question she has answered in an attempt to unfairly bias the sort order in favor of her answer and thereby increase her own reputation windfall.

So yes, if you downvote an answer from within one of the review queues, it will cost you 1 reputation point. This has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not you leave a comment. Comments don't cost you reputation, but they also don't affect the post's score, cause the poster to lose reputation, or do anything help to clean up the site.

If you are completely unwilling to tolerate the loss of 1 reputation point in the name of making the site a better resource for everyone, please steer clear of the review queues. Downvotes are a critical part of the interaction there, and if you've written this off as not-an-option, you won't be making the right call in certain cases. [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35376669/366904) *needed* a downvote. It also needed a delete vote. (Besides, if reputation is really *that* important to you, why are you wasting time reviewing when you could be contributing quality answers?)

*That said*, if an answer that you downvote is deleted, you get back the reputation that your downvote cost you. A nice little bonus.

Comment: The stated reason for having a 1 rep cost for downvotes is so that users will consider them, and ensure that a post really merits it.  It was not put in place to combat voting fraud.  That would imply that it was ever a common occurrence, which it really isn't, or that the rep cost would actually combat it, which it wouldn't.

Comment: I wondered about that last tidbit. My rep went down and then up. Now I know why.